# Cache to Avoid Database calls in validator : Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

## **What I am doing ?**

I am fetching the records from database in 2 ways.

### **Approach 1**

**Imposing the validation before saving the record**

```
$v = \Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'Category' => 'required|unique:tblcategory|max:25|min:5'
]);

if ($v->fails()) {
    return \Redirect::back()
                ->withErrors($v)
                ->withInput();
}
```

### **Approach 2**

**Fetching the records from database**

```
$Categories = \App\Models\Skill\Category_Model::all();
```

---

## **What's the question ?**

In Approach 2, I could avoid database calls by implementing the cache with below code `\Cache::put('Categories', $Categories, 60);`

**How can I avoid Database calls in case of Approach 1**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have a validator rule `unique:tblcategory`. [`unique` rule](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#rule-unique) will check the database if the category (I suppose, the id) exists. You can't really have that validation and expect it not to check the database.

**Caching the `unique` rule would be quite a weird way to go** since you REALLY don't want the values to duplicate which could happen if you cache the categories.

Comment: I don't think this question is about the unique modifier as much as it's about preventing a database call. Suppose the validation rule is 'exists' instead of 'unique'. That's perfectly reasonable to cache. Thus, the question remains: how do you cache the validation request?

Answer (score 2):

you could retrieve the categories. and then use it like so:

```
$cats = implode(',', $Categories);
$v = \Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'Category' => 'required|not_in:'.$cats.'|max:25|min:5'
]);
```